# gem sources add URL with "#" in it

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have gems repo installed at "http://somehost.com/repos/#/gems".

When I try to add this repo to sources:

```
gem sources --add "http://somehost.com/repos/#/gems/"
```

I see the following error:

```
Error fetching http://somehost.com/repos/#/gems/:
        bad response Not Found 404 (http://somehost.com/repos/specs.4.8.gz)
```

So it ignores everything after "#". How can I escape this character? I've also tried to URL encode "#" but this didn't help.

Comment: I don't get this error. Perhaps the host isn't accessible?